# Can a Service implement both MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener and MediaController.MediaPlayerControl?

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer

Hi I am trying to write an android app that will play MP3 files with the MediaPlayer implemented in a Service so that the audio file will continue to play if the user decides to open another activity or if the phone screen lock comes on.  I would also like to give the user a MediaController widget to use to play, stop, pause, rewind or fast forward.  I already have an app that plays the MP3 files in the Service but I want to add the MediaController now and I am having trouble understanding how this is done in a service.  I think I will have to "Bind" the service to my Activity but I am also unsure how that is done.

So my questions are:

1) how do I bind an Service and an Activity?

2) how do I implement MediaPlayer and MediaController in a Service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the MediaPlayer, study these docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

If it's a service you own, your activity can call `startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class))`. This will trigger the `onStartCommand` callback (even if the service has already been started). Your activities can also call `stopService(intent)` when you want the service to be stopped and subsequently destroyed. Services can also call `stopSelf()`.

"Binding" a service usually refers to services that belong to other processes that allow access for others to invoke methods across process boundaries. Unless that's what you're trying to do, you can probably ignore that.

Comment: I have been able to create an app that has a service that implements a media player and that works ok but I would like to be able to give the user a MediaController to control the playing of audio file. So where do initialize the MediaController? In the Service's `onStartCommand` or in the Activities `onCreate`?

Comment: You can put a MediaController in your Activity and respond to button clicks to start/stop your service. If you want the user to be able to play media while doing other tasks, you should leave an ongoing notification in the notification panel so that the user can easily get back to your Activity to access the media controls. On JellyBean you could also take advantage of the new Notification APIs and place some controls in the notification itself using `RemoteViews.`